Stream data from an Azure datastore into datasets object with `from_generator`
I have thousands of images files in an Azure datastore.  I'd like to stream them into a datasets object in an AzureML Jupyter notebook instance.
I'm using the code below, but it keeps running after 45 minutes with no end in sight:
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem
from datasets import Dataset

fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem('azureml://subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourcegroups/<rg_name>/workspaces/<ws_name>/datastores/<ds_name')

file_lst = fs.ls('datastore_subdir/')[1:]

def process_image():
    for file in file_lst:
        img = Image.open(fs.open(file))
        yield {'image': img}

image_ds = Dataset.from_generator(process_image)

I already have this working using the answer from this question.  However, would like to understand whether there's a way to get it to work using the generator approach.
For comparison, the following completes in 1.5 minutes:
import io

img_lst = []

for file in fs.ls('datastore_subdir/')[1:]:
    with fs.open(file) as f:
        print(counter)
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
        img_lst.append(img)



The Dataset.from_generator method is the most memory-efficient way to create a dataset. You can refer the documentation here about this.
It is also mentioned it is very useful for large dataset which doesn't fit in the memory.
If you are facing the performance issue like consuming more time that is because of the  large dataset generated on disk progressively.
So, if you have enough memory to hold such large dataset go with
Dataset.from_dict itself.
Additionally if you need you can generate list of images parallelly with concurrent.futures module.
Below is the sample code.
import io
from PIL import Image
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def load_and_process_images(file_list):
    def process_image(file):
        with fs.open(file) as f:
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
            return img

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        processed_images = list(executor.map(process_image, file_list))
    return processed_images



file_lst = fs.ls('Siirt_Pistachio/')
print(f"Total images {len(file_lst)}")
batch_size = 50  
processed_data = []

for i in range(0, len(file_lst), batch_size):
    batch_files = file_lst[i:i + batch_size]
    print(i)
    processed_data.extend(load_and_process_images(batch_files))

image_ds = Dataset.from_dict({'image':processed_data})

Output:


Thanks for the response.  I'm not following - is my original example with the generator approach correct?  If so, then my question is why does it take such a long time compared to the manual Image.open method?

Because of large dataset it might take time. And it is meant for memory efficient. Based on your use case need to select the approach.
